# How to back up and restore the Visual soucesafe code and Databse

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, vb6, visual-sourcesafe

Can any on explain how to take back up and restore the Visual source safe code and database.

I wanted to migrate the code and database from older server to new server.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Source Safe provides inbuilt tools do achieve this (**Archive** and **Restore** projects). You should be logged into Visual Source Safe as **Visual Source Safe Administrator** to access these options.

This [Link](http://www.codepool.biz/how-to-backup-restore-sourcesafe-vss-database.html) provides the step by step procedure to Archive & restore projects in Visual Source Safe.